# Types for Google Maps JS Autocomplete don't return the same address_components

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` to attach autosuggest address/city to an input field. We need to support both full addresses and cities, so I use the types of `["street_number", "street_address", "route", "locality"]`, but we had some complaints that some of the addresses weren't correct. I dug into and was able to replicate the issue. I first changed the types to just be `["address"]` and then everything worked as expected.

What I found is there is a missing `address_component` when using `["street_number", "street_address", "route", "locality"]` vs `["address"]`.

Google maps version: `3.55.4`

I have created a [fiddle for the following here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lht8sv5j/2/)

Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Select "address" option
2. Enter "10800 I-27, Amarillo, TX 79119"
3. Select the first result from the autosuggest
4. Look at the console and look at the "address_components" section, which there will be 8 listed
5. Select the "street number" option
6. Enter the same address from step 2 above
7. Look at the console and look at the "address_components" section, which there will be only 5 with "street_number" missing

```
// This is using types of ["address"]
[
    {
        "long_name": "10800",
        "short_name": "10800",
        "types": [
            "street_number"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Interstate 27",
        "short_name": "I-27",
        "types": [
            "route"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Amarillo",
        "short_name": "Amarillo",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Randall County",
        "short_name": "Randall County",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Texas",
        "short_name": "TX",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "United States",
        "short_name": "US",
        "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "79119",
        "short_name": "79119",
        "types": [
            "postal_code"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "2526",
        "short_name": "2526",
        "types": [
            "postal_code_suffix"
        ]
    }
]

// This is using types of ["street_number", "route", "locality"]
// I even tried types of ["street_number", "route", "locality", "street_address"]
[
    {
        "long_name": "Interstate 27",
        "short_name": "I-27",
        "types": [
            "route"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Amarillo",
        "short_name": "Amarillo",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Potter County",
        "short_name": "Potter County",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Texas",
        "short_name": "TX",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "United States",
        "short_name": "US",
        "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have added the type of `"street_address"` to see if that would help, but it hasn't.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and why it works with `"address"` over the individual parts.

Comment: If you look at the place_id of the returned place in those two cases, it is different (`address`: `ChIJoRDdoxRbAYcRhC4lmbBCsqA`, `street number`: `EhdJLTI3LCBBbWFyaWxsbywgVFgsIFVTQSIuKiwKFAoSCdHTE43skwGHEdaA1x2Hvso0EhQKEgkDz0Wy1EgBhxGv0jZoHNHz0A`)

Comment: @geocodezip would that really matter for the components? To me that doesn't really make sense, but I am a novice at google map stuff.

Comment: It is a different place that is being returned, so it could (and does) have different address components.

Comment: @geocodezip but I'm entering the same address for both, so how would I go about fixing that? I guess I don't understand the difference that `types` play when entering the same address

Comment: This might help (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#:~:text=The%20format%20of,a%20later%20response.)

Comment: @Yrll I did see that, but this is consistently different. Not just between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The API is working as intended if it did not return the same component when changing types

I'd like to quote **geocodezip** above for his findings on the comments as reference of this answer:

> If you look at the `place_id` of the returned place in those two cases, it is different
>
> - **address**: `ChIJoRDdoxRbAYcRhC4lmbBCsqA`,
> - **street number**: `EhdJLTI3LCBBbWFyaWxsbywgVFgsIFVTQSIuKiwKFAoSCdHTE43skwGHEdaA1x2Hvso0EhQKEgkDz0Wy1EgBhxGv0jZoHNHz0A`

As you have noticed, when changing the `types` for the search into `street_number`, it returns a very long `place_id`. This could mean that the returned result was a **Synthetic Address** when changing the `types`.

As explained by the [Google Maps Platform documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/architecture/geocoding-address-validation#synthetic_addresses),

> *The Geocoding API may return locations for "synthetic" addresses that don't exist as precise locations in Google’s database.*
>
> *In such scenarios the response object often contains a **long Place ID**.*

Since the Places API uses Geocoding API to a certain extent, this could only mean that a street address for `10800 I-27, Amarillo, TX 79119` **does not exist** and the API tried its best to provide an approximate location.

I tried looking further but the address `10800 I-27, Amarillo, TX 79119` was an actual address with `types` as `premise`.

So it would make sense that if you try to search this specific address as a street address or route, the API would not find it in it's database, so it makes an approximate location of a "route" as a **Synthetic Result**.

As mentioned by the [Address Validation documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/architecture/geocoding-address-validation#synthetic_addresses:%7E:text=If%20you%20encounter%20these%20indicators%20in%20the%20response%2C%20please%20consider%20marking%20the%20input%20address%20as%20an%20invalid%20and%20try%20to%20re%2Dvalidate%20it%20by%20another%20means.),

> *"If you encounter these indicators in the response, please consider marking the input address as an invalid and try to re-validate it by another means."*

If your use case needs you to have a valid address, I'd suggest you use [Address Validation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/reference/rest) or just use the `address` types to return specific addresses instead of routes.

Comment: Thanks @Yrll! This helped me narrow down to the type that I was missing (`premise`). I wish google would list all types that are supported under their `address` type (table 3). Since we need to also search by cities, the `address` type can't be used.

Comment: Great to hear that this helped! You can then just follow the implementation sample you provided in your question where customers can change the types themselves. [Places Types Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table1:~:text=may%20be%20indeterminate.-,address,-instructs%20the%20Place) says that `address` types instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.

Comment: unfortunately, we need the detection to be automatic (no user interaction for changing types). The `address` type is everything we want excluding the ability to search by cities, which is why it lead me down this road as to think something we wrong (a bug with the service).

Comment: how did you find out that the type was `premise`? The reason I ask is because we have found another address that doesn't work properly ("77860 Bombing Range Rd , Boardman, OR") and I'm not sure what type I need to add to support it. Thanks!

Comment: Does your use case does not have any user interaction at all? I got the types `premise` just by using Geocoding API. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&address=10800%20I-27%2C%20Amarillo%2C%20TX%2079119

Comment: With regards to "77860 Bombing Range Rd , Boardman, OR", what is your expected result?

Comment: Ah, I see how you get the types now. That will come in handy! Thanks for that!

Comment: >Does your use case does not have any user interaction at all?

Yes, they enter an address via an input, then my scripts split that out into street info (number and name), city, state, and zip.

Comment: As for "77860 Bombing Range Rd , Boardman, OR", I expect 77860 Bombing Range Rd to have a `street_number`, but when I do the search with the types of `['premise', 'street_number', 'route', 'street_address', 'locality']`, I only get `["route", "administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_1", "country"]` back.

Comment: I used https://jsfiddle.net/3s9u4jmh/1/ for testing this (I also have a screenshot of the console output to confirm)